# How to check if a tag exists in a measurement using flux?

Tags: influxdb

How to check if a specific tag exists in a measurement using flux language?
My influxdb version is 2.0.

Comment: Could you please post your efforts in your question(what you tried) that's highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: I have the same question too, so i might expand it if this is ok, rather than asking another...

Comment: nvm. I found out the answer while rubber duck debugging ;)

Answer (score 3):

simple you need to add a filter for the tag name you need to filter to your flux query. let's say the tag name is "tag_name":

`|> filter(fn: (r) => exists r.tag_name)`

this will filter any undefined or "unset" tag.

Answer (score 2):

(answering for my usecase, since no details were provided)

TL;DR: use the [exists operator](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/flux/language/operators/#logical-operators).

Imagine a dataset which has this old tag, which we don't care about anymore, and we want to filter out those records when archiving:

```
option task = {
  name: "15min_archive",
  every: 1w,
}

from(bucket: "mybucket")
 |> range(start: - duration(v: int(v: task.every) * 2))
// this:
 |> filter(fn: (r) => (exists r["stupidOldTag"] ) == false )
 |> aggregateWindow(every: 15m, fn: mean)
// ...
```

**note:** the `==false` because `not` is apparently not a thing yet.